# Comparison between native types JavaScript, Class is same than {}?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, javascriptcore

I'm writing some tests about the comparison between `Class` and `Object` in Javascript. And I have some doubt about the real objective with `Class` in JS.

If everything is an `object`(except primitives types) is correct to state that:

```js
class Foo {
    static anyFunc () {}
}
const FooInstance = new Foo();
```

is equal

```js
const FooInstance = {
    anyFunc () {}
}
```

?

How I can measure the performance/memory allocated/sizeof of these implementations? Can be in C++ or JS.

Thanks so much!

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes): "JavaScript classes, introduced in ECMAScript 2015, are primarily syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax does not introduce a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript."

Comment: There are no classes, there is class syntax. There are objects and primitives. The two examples are not "equal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const FooInstance = {
    anyFunc () {}
}
```

`FooInstance` in this case is directly an instance of `Object`. If you look at its prototype chain, it's immediately `Object`. `anyFunc` method will be found on the instance itself.

```
class Foo {
  static anyFunc () {}
}
const FooInstance = new Foo();
```

`FooInstance` in this case is an instance of `Foo` (and `Object` too since all objects descend from it). If you look at its prototype chain it will have the prototype of `Foo` first, then the prototype of `Object` next. Additionally, `anyFunc` is not a method on the instance (nor the prototype). It will be attached on the constructor itself (i.e. `Foo.anyFunc()` or `FooInstance.constructor.anyFunc()`, but not `FooInstance.anyFunc()`).

In short, no. They're not equal.

Visually, the chain would look like:

```
// First case:
instance ---> Object.prototype
- anyFunc

// Second case:
instance -> Foo.prototype -------> Object.prototype
            - constructor (Foo)
              - anyFunc
```

> How I can measure the performance/memory allocated/sizeof of these implementations?

It's negligble. Don't worry about it. Or worry about it only when it becomes a problem.